# Entity Framework Audit log - Tracing changes in virtual objects

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, audit-logging

Based on [how to create an audit trail with Entity framework 5 and MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20961576/3544503) question I am trying to figgure out how can I track changes in virtual/foreign objects.

On the line which compares the OriginalValues to the CurrentValues it does not include the fields for the virtual objects that where changed.

```
if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
```

Is there an easy fix for this where I can specify in my controller method that x and y virtual objects might also have been changed? Or maybe look up the original and current values of those connected to the current dbEntry in the dbEntry.State == EntityState.Modified section?

Comment: What is a "virtual object"?

Comment: Foreign key obect. One to many relation. Public virtual ICollection<T> SomeObject { get; set; }